# Angular JS dropdown list is not showing value to ng-selected="selected"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS, facing problem with `ng-option`, `selected='selected'` is not showing in the combobox.

Below is the select HTML element and data source:

```
<select class="form-control" id="numberOfRows" ng-model="prefferedLanguage"
       ng-change="changePreference(prefferedLanguage)">
    <option my-repeat="language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference" value="{{language.LanguageISOCode}}"
            ng-selected="{{language.IsDefault == true}}">
        {{language.LanguageName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

**sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference** :

```
"LanguagePreference": [
    {
      "LanguageISOCode": "EN",
      "LanguageName": "English",
      "IsDefault": true
    },
    {
      "LanguageISOCode": "FR",
      "LanguageName": "French",
      "IsDefault": false
    }
  ]
```

I want to set combo box value depending on the Property "IsDefault" of the Model on page Load. But it is not working.

Generated HTML is:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" id="numberOfRows" ng-model="prefferedLanguage" ng-change="changePreference(prefferedLanguage)"><option value="? undefined:undefined ?"></option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference --><option my-repeat="language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference" value="EN" ng-selected="true" ng-repeat="language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference" class="ng-binding ng-scope" selected="selected">
        English
    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference --><option my-repeat="language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference" value="FR" ng-selected="false" ng-repeat="language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
        French
    </option><!-- end ngRepeat: language in sirCommonService.LOVData.LanguagePreference -->
</select>
```

Comment: dont use selected="selected", in other way u can use **ng-init="prefferedLanguage.LanguageName = English"**

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle the select is by using the **select** directive with **ngOptions**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

I had the same problem as you before. Its just not working well with ngRepeat and options.

Comment: That won't work for question asked. They want to select the item based on their data

Comment: @KScandrett you just set ngModel to the value you need.

Comment: ngModel cannot be set to the isDefault value from their json data because the ngModel value is not a boolean value. Also their json data will be changed/corrupted when the selection changes

Answer (score 1):

i've just created a plnkr here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/rCQzEhojZP0iHvoI1KlO?p=preview

you should use select with ng-options , something like this

```
 <select
        ng-model="defaultlanguage" 
        ng-options="lan.LanguageISOCode for lan in LanguagePreference">
 </select>
```

Comment: i'm glad that it helped you, hope you can give me a +1

Answer (score 0):

**ng-selected** directive takes an expression as a parameter. So, change your code as following :

```
ng-selected="language.IsDefault == true"
```